# MS-Project - How to set 1 resource with 2 kind of work and monitor time/rate for each

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, ms-project-2013

I'm using Project 2013; client requested this tool for activities tracking and management.

Actually the project have one developer assigned that work 6h per day and can have assigned two kind of work:

- Maintenance (with a monthly hour limit set to 120h)
- Development (with an day rate, pay per performance)

The problem is that the client sent me a file with two resources set, one for the Maintenance and on for Development.
This lead to a problem when I set concatenate activities:
I've one physical developer available, but project sees two resources, and can occour that one day I have 6h for maintenance and 6h for evolutive assigned to the same physical developer when concatenating tasks (that usually will be splitted between days if longer than 6h).
That's right from Project's perspective as one resource is one developer, but in my case the two resources lead to a single person that can work 6h per day, not 12h.

This Project file setting of 2 resources with 1 developer was done because the client would like to monitor the time spent for the two different kind of work, but from what I've understood with Project, that's not the best way to do it.

Can you suggest a setting that can monitor one resource with 2 different kind of work with 2 different rates (1 hour rate and 1 hour limit per month)?

**UPDATE:**
Actually I've studied a bit the behaviour and use of custom fields, and I've found the way to have a custom field shown in both "GANTT chart" view and in "Resource usage" view (I've set one task custom field and one project custom field with the same text values) with the values set to "WDM (web development maintenance)" or "WDE (web development evolutive)".
Then, following another question here in pm.stackexchange, I've created a macro that when fired, fills the "Resource usage" custom "Task type" column, with the same values that I set on the "GANTT chart" view "Task type column.
What I miss is the hours sum of the tasks assigned as WDM and the sum of the tasks assigned as WDE.
Into "Resource sheet" I can see the total amount of work, but would be nice to set another couple of custom fields into this view that show the sum of WDM and the sum of WDE.

**Screenhsots**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Solved with JulieS tips:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get part of the solution through grouping.  Now that you have copied the Task data to the assignment rows, in the Resource usage view group by Resources and then by the custom field "Task Type".  You'll need to group on assignments to get able to get the Task Type field to work correctly. That should give you work per assignment type.

You cannot set a limit of the number of hours.  I would also suggest replacing the resources on the second set of tasks - so they all use the same resource.  You can then check for resource overallocations so the resource is not scheduled for 12 hours in a single day.  I also assume the maintenance tasks are lower priority, so if you are going to resolve the overallocations by leveling, set the maintenance tasks to lower priority and then level by Priority, Standard order.

As far as different rates - you can create different cost rate tables for the resource and using the Resource Usage view - change to the different rate.  Add the Cost Rate Table field to the view to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks JulieS, i studied a bit the grouping function, added like you adviced and i can say that now works like a charm.
Thank you so much, you made my day!

Comment: Great.  Glad to know you have it sorted and working as you need.  Thanks for the feedback.